# How to change the edge routing style in a JGraphX graph using mxCell class?

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

How can I change the routing style of the edges using the mxCell class?

```
for (mxCell cell : cells) {
    mxGraph.setCellStyle("edgeStyle=" + edge style + ";", new Object[] { cell });
}
```

Can I have something like that?

Comment: If you want to change it for every edge you can use: `mxGraph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle().put(mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE, /*your desired style e.g. mxConstants.EDGESTYLE_ELBOW*/)`

Comment: I wanted to change the style of certain edges. Actually, the code I have provided above worked perfectly. I got a style name from mxConstants which corresponds to a String instead of getting an edge style from mxEdgeStyle which returns a function.

Comment: Then use `mxCell#setStyle(String style)`. The cell doesn't care whether it's an edge or vertex. Or you can use `if(mxCell.isEdge()){mxCell.setStyle("whatever");}`